# Application Insights strategies for web api serving multiple clients

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

We have a back end API, running ASP.Net Core, with two front ends: A SPA web site (Vuejs) and a progressive web page (for mobile users). The front ends are basically only client code and all services are on different domains. We don't use cookies as authentication uses bearer tokens.

We've been playing with Application Insights for monitoring, but as the documentation is not very descriptive for our situations, I would like to get some more inputs for what is the best strategy and possibilities for:

- Tracking users and metrics without cookies from e.g. the button click in the applications to the server call, Entity Framework/SQL query (I see that this is currently not supported, [How to enable dependency tracking with Application Insights in an Asp.Net Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674695/how-to-enable-dependency-tracking-with-application-insights-in-an-asp-net-core-p)), processing data and presentation of the result on the client.
- Separating calls from mobile and standard web in an easy manner in Application Insights queries. Any way to show this in the standard charts that show up initially would be beneficial.
- Making sure that our strategy will also fit in situations where other external clients will access the API, and we should be able to identify these easily, and see how much load they are creating for the system.
- Doing all of the above with the least amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be worthy of several independent questions if you want specifics on any of them.  (and generally your last bullet is always implied, isn't it? :))

What have you tried so far?  most of the "best way for you" kinds of things are going to be opinions though.

For general answers:

- re: tracking users...

If you're already doing user info/auth for other purposes, you'd just set the various `context.user.*` fields with the info you have on the incoming request's telemetry context.  all other telemetry that occurs using that same telemetry context would then inerit whatever user info you already have.

- re: separating calls from mobile and standard...

if you're already doing this as different services/domains, and you are already using the same instrumentation key for both places, then the domain/host info of pageviews or requests is already there, you can filter/group on this in the portal or make custom queries in the analytics portal to analyze that way. if you know which site it is regardless of the host, you could add that as custom properties in the telemetry context, you could also do that to avoid dealing with host info.

- re: external callers via an api

similarly, if you're already exposing an api and using auth, you should (ideally) already know who the inbound callers are, and you can set that info in custom properties as well.

**In general**, [custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#properties) (string:string key value pairs) and custom metrics (string:double key value pairs) are your friends. you can set them on contexts so all the events generated in that context inherit the same properties, you can explicitly set them on individual `TrackEvent` (or any of the other `Track*` calls) to send specific properties/metrics with any single event.

You can also use [telemetry initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling) to augment or filter any telemetry that's being generated automatically (like requests or dependencies on the server side, or page views and ajax dependencies client side)